# Какой алгоритм мне лучше использовать?

Tags: python, алгоритм, парсер, http, url

Пишу свою библиотеку на python для создания веб-приложений. Сейчас делаю классы и функции, которые должны сравнивать запрашиваемый url, и url который записан в специальном файле (urls.py). Проблема с динамическими путями, не знаю как лучше распарсить строку и вытащить из неё данные. Допустим у есть такой путь:

```
/api/v1/news/detail/int:id/
```

Этот пусть записан в файле urls.py. Последний параметр `int:id` означает, что на этом месте может быть любое число типа integer. id - это название аргумента в который нужно передать значение в функцию (не играет никакой роли сейчас).
Представим, что на сервер поступает запрос по такому пути:

```
/api/v1/news/detail/1/
```

Нужно проверить, чтобы он соответствовал пути в urls.py. С этим проблем нет, сервер при запуске составляет регулярные выражения для всех путей и при запросе проверяет, соответствует ли запрашиваемый путь одному из регулярных выражений. Вопрос как вытащить из этого пути именно значение id? Я конечно знаю как, крутить вертеть туда сюда вырезая всё ненужное и сплитить. Сейчас пришёл к такому варианту - берётся оба пути `/api/v1/news/detail/1/` и `/api/v1/news/detail/int:id/`. к обоим применяется метод `split`. Получаю 2 списка. Удаляю из них одинаковые элементы. Оставшиеся элементы по порядку попарно соединяю в словарь и получаю {'id': '1'}. Но мне кажется это не совсем быстро и есть какой-то более быстрый и элегантный способ. Я не прошу код, просто натолкните на мысль, как можно сделать лучше. Если есть какие-то повторяющиеся действия (например составить регулярные выражения), то можно их можно выполнять до запуска сервера и сохранять в переменные необходимую информацию.

P.S. Не нужно мне предлагать всякие джанги и aiohttp, не хочу я их использовать! НЕ ХОЧУ!!!

Comment: 1) велосипеды наше всё) 2) если в шаблоне будет "/str:id/", то id="str:id" заглючит 3) вроде в самих регулярках были средства захватить кусок совпадения и дать ему имя

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov не заглючит, потому что `:` должно кодироваться специальными знаками по спецификации http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m = re.match(r'(?P<first>\w+) (?P<last>\w+)', 'Jane Doe')
m.groupdict()
{'first': 'Jane', 'last': 'Doe'}
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что так можно. Вопрос только, что значит `?P` в регулярке?

Comment: это named groups capturing